# why does "ら" follow "山中{やまなか}" here: "山中ら、予備検診{よびけんしん}で異常{いじょう}なし"

Tags: words, plurals

In the newspaper article titled [山中ら、予備検診で異常なし…ＷＢＣバンタム級](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/sports/etc/20150413-OYT1T50109.html), what meaning is created by placing "ら" after "山中"?

Does it make "山中慎介" plural, and then "山中ら" means something like "Yamanaka and his hangers-on".

Maybe, "Clintonら" means "Hillary Clinton and her senior campaign staff"?

Comment: Since you didn't just write "yes", then I am not sure I understand. So, I can take a person's name, add "ら", then there is a vague range of people included in the newly created group? Please translate that title into english so I understand.

Comment: Afraid it is not a simple yes with "Yamanaka and his hangers-on".  Wrote an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「ら」 is a plural suffix.

In this case, 「山中ら」 just means "Yamanaka and his opponent", ***not*** "Yamanaka and his hangers-on".  The hangers-on do not need to take a preliminary physical before a boxing match.

"Yamanaka and his opponent pass their preliminary physical."

Comment: The title is not "ディエゴ・サンティリャンら、予備検診で..." because (1) Diego is the challenger? (2) as yomiuri is a Japanese newspaper,  reader focus is on the Japanese fighter?  (3) simply, "ディエゴ・サンティリャンら、..." makes for an unwieldy title?

Comment: I'd say 2 is the primary reason. Just like when talking about a local team's game, we don't mention the opponent (in LA, we'd say the Dodger's game and not say, the Yankee's game).  Plus, it's more likely Japanese people would be more familiar with the Japanese boxer, making it a natural choice as a title.

Comment: Also because newspaper headlines must be short.